# JPA relationship in Single Table inheritance

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

The setup is JPA/Eclipselink 2.6; Spring JPA 4.1.6
The following entities:

**Mother**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(...)
public class Mother implements Serializable {
//...
}
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(...)
public class Child extends Mother{
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "another_entity_id", updatable=false)
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
  private AnotherEntity anotherEntity;

//... getter,setters, the works
}
```

Now, if I saveAndFlush with a JpaRepository or JpaRepository it guesses the name from the attribute instead of the annotation (in this case anotherEntity instead of another_entity_id), which obviously fails; also, if I set the attribute name to match the column name, it complains that I want to save a bytea (object) in a integer column.

Looks like a bug, right?

Comment: You have annotated your ManyToOne with Basic. These two are mutually exclusive: either it's a basic field, or it's an association. Not both.

Comment: Why do you have `updatable=false` on the `@JoinColumn`?

Comment: JB, thanks. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: More sleep, less dumb mistakes :) -- I copy pasted it from another field.

Comment: @Duncan -- it's for a logging functionality: the linked entity should be inserted when the log entry is created, but not modified afterwards (whereas the entry itself may be updated)